# entity cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I get this error each time I try to attach an User to a Group (or creating a Group).

Here is the GroupController :

```
public class GroupsController : Controller
{
       private Context db = new Context();

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Group group)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                group.owner = db.Users.Attach((User)Session["user"]);
    //current user stored in session
                db.Groups.Add(group);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View(group);
        }
}
```

The variable Session["user"] is set at logon, here is the AccountController code :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LoginTemplate login, string returnUrl)
    {

            User result = db.Users.Where(m => m.email == login.email).Where(m => m.password == login.password).SingleOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                Session["logged"] = true;
                Session["user"] = result;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
     }
 }
```

Here is my context :

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context() : base("name=myContext")
    {
    }
    private static Context _instance;

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

//I tried to use this method in order to always get the same context but does not work

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new Context();
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Here is User.cs

```
       public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int userId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Firstname")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lastname")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> membership { get; set;}

}
```

Here is group.cs :

```
        public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int idGroup { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public User owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> members { get; set; }

}
```

I tried to do a "singleton" in my Context (to always reuse the same context in each controller) but when I do that, I get "Db closed" error message...

Comment: Are you sure that the Context is singleton "private Context db = new Context();" ? public Context() : base("name=myContext") change access modifier to private. Where are you get error exactly?

Comment: “An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker”
I used to try with singleton but it doesn't work, that's why i put "private Context db = new Context()" back

Comment: "I used to try with singleton but it doesn't work." What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

### INITIAL ANSWER

What you describe seems expected behaviour to me.

What happens?

1. When you log on a user entity is loaded, and saved in the session. But since the context that is tracking the user entity has references to the user entity, and more importantly, the user entity has references to the context, the context is not disposed of, and even though your controller will be garbage collected, the context is not.
2. The group-controller is instanced, and this has a separate context. Then you create a group entity, and at that point the group entity has no references yet to the context (or the other way around). So connecting the user entity to the group entity is fine. But when you attach the group entity to the new context, the context starts tracking this entity, and all other entities that are referenced by the group entity. So that includes the user entity. Since the original context is also tracking the user entity, this results in the exception.

I can see an easy solution, and that is to use the id of the user entity instead of the object itself, when you want to connect the user entity to the group entity. This way, no references are created between the group entity and the user entity, so that should work fine.

### UPDATE

Upon second read I see that you do not have a user-id property in the group entity, so my solution would not work.

Comment: If the user object in session state is still connected to a context, it may be worth considering if it needs to be. Detaching it will potentially free up database connections and will avoid unintended effects such as this error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the `virtual` keyword of your entity's navigation properties. EF will create a lazy loading proxy then that is capable to load the navigation properties on the fly but to do this it needs to hold a reference to the context. When you attach the entity later to another context you get this exception because the proxy is still tracked by the old context it is pointing to.

You can probably fix the error by disabling proxy creation and tracking when you load the user to ensure that a pure (non-proxy) POCO entity is loaded that doesn't reference the context anymore:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    public AccountController()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LoginTemplate login, string returnUrl)
    {
        User result = db.Users.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(m => m.email == login.email)
            .Where(m => m.password == login.password)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            Session["logged"] = true;
            Session["user"] = result;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

It will disable proxies and lazy loading for the whole controller but you can replace it with eager loading (`Include`) when you need navigation properties to be loaded.

Even if that fixes your problem it is still not the best practice in my opinion to store an entity in session state. Better use a specialized `UserForSessionModel` class (that is not a database entity) or store only the `Id` and reload the user from the database when you need it.

**Edit**

You can alternatively use a "stub entity" in your `Create` action to avoid to attach the loaded user that is referenced by another context:

```
var userStub = new User { userId = ((User)Session["user"]).userId };
group.owner = db.Users.Attach(userStub);
db.Groups.Add(group);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The only thing you need from the user to establish a relationship is its primary key, so such an empty user with only the key populated is sufficient.

Comment: Don't think Lazy Loading affects update behaviour, only auto-loads related entities when they referenced and have not already been retrieved.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: It doesn't affect the update but it affects that EF will create a proxy that references the context including its change tracker (= "instance of `IEntityChangeTracker`"). When you attach to another context EF recognizes that the entity still references the old context - which throws the exception.

Comment: True, but I think the error occurs as the code attempts to attach a user object to the context that is already attached (as described below).

Comment: @PaulTaylor: No, that would result in another exception: "*An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key*" which has a quite different reason than the exception in the question.

Comment: Interesting, what is the reason? The two error messages sound related to me. I would expect that the one that you get depends on whether you are using self-tracking entities or not.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Here are no self-tracking entities in play. The exception in the question has to do with multiple contexts in place that track the same entity (only one object), the other exception occurs with a single context (more than one object (with the same key)).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use db.Users.Attach with the User object saved in session state. The object you want to save is the new Group, not the user. My guess is that the exception is thrown when you call db.Users.Attach((User)Session["user"]), and that may indicate that the entity of the current user is already being managed in the current context by EF.

Comment: I agree with you...
But when I do  group.owner = (User)Session["user"]; the exception is thrown at db.Groups.Add(group);

Comment: It works now with group.owner = Session["user"] but i get duplicate content in user table

Comment: @Tang When you save a new entity using a context, all extra entities which are not yet tracked but are referenced by the new entity, are always saved with the same state. So in this case, if you save a new group entity, any referenced user entities are also saved as new entities. So that would explain the duplicate content.

Comment: @Tang If the user is duplicated in the database, what is the Id value of the new record? Is it duplicated too? (If it is, it suggests that the Id is not defined as a primary key in the user table: you might want to make it the PK. As it stands, you may be able to avoid the duplication by setting `db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged` before saving the group entity.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error when I had a Caching layer that was caching look-up Entities and retrieving them from the cache. The cached entities were proxy entities and still had a reference to the DBContext that originally retrieved them.

The main symptom of this is that the first save of a Domain entity with a look up reference worked okay, but subsequent saves failed.

I hope this helps someone, as the problem took 2 days off my life.